# Can someone explain this step to me (Proof of Extension of Extension theorem)

Tags: probability-theory, elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

Corollary: Let $\mathcal{J}$ be a semi algebra of subsets of $\Omega$. Let $P:\mathcal{J}\to [0,1]$ with and $P(\Omega)$=1, and $P$ satisfy countable additivity that:
$$
P(\cup_n D_n ) = \sum_n P(D_n)\text{ for }D_1,D_2,\dots \in \mathcal{J} \text{ disjoint with } \cup_n D_n \in \mathcal{J} \tag{2.5.5}
$$There there is $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{M}\supseteq\mathcal{J}$, and a countably additive probability measure $P^*$ on $\mathcal{M}$ such that $P^*(A)=P(A) \forall A\in\mathcal{J}$.

NOTE: It is proven already that $P(\emptyset) = 0$, and that finite superadditivity is satisfied (with equality). It has also been proven that
$$P(A)\leq P(B) \text{ whenever }A,B\in \mathcal{J} \text{ with }A\subseteq B \tag{2.5.2}$$

**PROVE:** 
$$P\big( \cup _n B_n \big) \leq \sum _n P(B_n) \text{ for }B_1,B_2,\dots \in\mathcal{J} \text{ with }\cup _n B_n\in \mathcal{J} \tag{2.5.3}$$

Here is the proof:
[image]

**MY Question** I am confused on the second/third/fourth equality. What was the purpose of breaking the $D_n$ sets down further into finite sets? and then regrouping them. We already know that $D_n \in \mathcal{J}$ and are disjoint, so it can't be for those properties... Unless it is just to be thorough?

Note, I know HOW the steps are derived. I just don't see why decomposing that far is necessary.

EDIT: Image, proof, and definitions taken from Rosenthal's Introduction to Probability theory

Comment: How do you know that $D_n \in J$? This will depend on the definition of a "semi-algebra", but I don't know that definition. But I conjecture that $D_n \in J$ might not actually hold.

Comment: Definition is contains null set, sample space, closed under finite intersection and the complement of something is a finite disjoint Union of other things in the semialgebra. So you're right, we need the step because $D_n$ may not be in $\mathcal{J}$. I was thinking since $D_n \subseteq B_n$ it must be in $\mathcal{J}$, but I guess that's not true. For example if $B_n =\{1,2,3\}\ ,D_n=\{1,2\}$, $\{1,2\}$ maybe isn't in $\mathcal{J}$. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem (as was pointed out by @PhoemueX) is that there is no warranty that $D_n$ are in the semi-algebra. Consider the following example: 
\begin{array}{lll}
B_1 & = & \left[ \frac{1}{3},\frac{3}{4} \right], \\
B_2 & = & \left[ 0,1 \right].
\end{array}
Where clearly, $B_1,B_2 \in \mathcal{J} = \left \{ \textrm{ all intervals in } [0,1] \right \}$. Consider now: 
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
D_1 &= B_1,\\
D_2 & = B_1^C \cap B_2 = \left[0,\frac{1}{3}\right) \bigcup \left(\frac{3}{4},1\right]
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Clearly $D_2$ is not an interval and thus it does not belong to $\mathcal{J}$. But $D_2$ can be written as a countable union of elements of $\mathcal{J}$ and thus the second/third/fourth equalities.